# Asking Google Play if an in app purchase has been purchased by a user

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, bundle

I have an in app purchase for premium features that currently when you purchase it it will edit a shared preference that gives you the premium features. I would like it if every time you opened the app it would find out from google play if the user has purchased premium so that if  user switches devices they will not have to re purchase premium. I assume that to do this I would need to use the "Querying for Purchased Items" part of google's tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

```
ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(
            "com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
    bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    try {
        Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code compiles with no errors and if I remove the line to receive the Bundle of owned items the app will not crash. However if I try to actually receive the information the app will crash. I have the code shown above in the onCreate() method and I have mService and mServiceConn introduced in the top of the java file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bindService()` is an asynchronous operation, meaning your mService will almost certainly be null immediately after calling `bindService()`.

You need to wait for `onServiceConnected()` to be called and you receive a valid `mService` before querying for your purchases - either move your `try` block into `onServiceConnected()` or have that in a method that is called by `onServiceConnected()`.

Comment: Thanks I was having the problem you described of using an asynchronous operation incorrectly.

Comment: If this helped, please make sure you accept the answer to remove it from the unanswered queue.